# Saving an image to imageview picked from gallery in API 30

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this is the code i'm using for picking an image form gallery and use it for profile picture on the app. it works fine with all the versions below API 30. how can i make it work in all versions of AI can anybody help?

```
        profilresmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT );
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,CHOOSE_IMAGE);

        }
    });


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        profilresmi.setImageURI(imageUri);


        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("profil", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

        editor.putString("imageuri", imageUri.toString());
        editor.commit();


    }
}



private  void setimage(){
    SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences("profil",MODE_APPEND);
    String imageUriString = sh.getString("imageuri", "");


    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUriString);
    if(imageUri.toString().length() == 0){

    }else {
        profilresmi.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? You are doing more then one thing so...

Comment: When i close the app and open again it's crashing in api 30. below 30 it works fine the selected picture from gallery sets on imageview as a profile picture.

Comment: Which code is executed when you open the app again? Why should we guess if you can tell?

Comment: i put setimage() under oncreate so profile picture was set when app opening.

Comment: plz share error